# How to set only the hour for a django DateTimeField using update

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have a long list of entries that have a field

`date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`

This field use to  be a DateField only and now i changed it to datetime. 
After the migration the existing entries have the default hour set to midgnig (00). I would like to update that for all entries to be to 9 AM.

I would like something like this:

`Entry.objects.all().update(date__hour=9)`

but this does not work as it raises and exception:

django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Entry has no field named 'date__hour'

Any suggestions?
Thanks

EDIT 1: the list is of entries is big, above 1 million entries. Therefore I would like a database mass update, not a one by one solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have no project right now to test. But can you try like this.

```
for e in Entry.objects.all():
    e.date += timedelta(0, 9*3600)
    e.save()
```

The above will work as you have 00 in hours each object. But if you want to statically replace date object with 9 AM which has different value in each date object. You can do like below.

```
for e in Entry.objects.all():
    e.date = e.date.replace(hour=9)
    e.save()
```

Hope this slove your problem.

Comment: Thanks. This would work and I know this solution, but I am searching for a database level update (mass update). The number of entries is big (more than 1 million) and this would take too much. I updated my question to be more exact.

Comment: I don't think you have any other solution directly with ORM. May be you have to use Raw SQL query. BTW I believe this will take same time what other approaches with ORM (Until you are not going with SQL query)